# DLL Hell with .NET Core Class Library

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, dll, class-library

I'm building a COM Library to expose SignalR to a non-NET software but it has a lot of references loading different versions, I even lost a lot of time trying to get the strict version of everything but it just breaks even more.
Using the library on a test Console App works fine because of the binding redirections on the app.config of the EXE but I can't put a .config file on the production EXE.
I hope I have other alternatives than this.

Real example (Assembly Binding Log Viewer)

```
*** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (29/06/2021 @ 14:02:43) ***

The operation failed.
Bind result: hr = 0x80070002. The system cannot find the file specified.

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  C:\Program Files (x86)\Sybase\PowerBuilder 11.5\PB115.EXE
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = System.Text.Json, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Sybase/PowerBuilder 11.5/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL
LOG: Cache Base = NULL
LOG: AppName = PB115.EXE
Calling assembly : Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Protocols.Json, Version=5.0.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60.
===
LOG: This bind starts in LoadFrom load context.
WRN: Native image will not be probed in LoadFrom context. Native image will only be probed in default load context, like with Assembly.Load().
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Sybase\PowerBuilder 11.5\PB115.EXE.Config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: System.Text.Json, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51
LOG: GAC Lookup was unsuccessful.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Sybase/PowerBuilder 11.5/System.Text.Json.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Sybase/PowerBuilder 11.5/System.Text.Json/System.Text.Json.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Sybase/PowerBuilder 11.5/DotNET/bin/System.Text.Json.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Sybase/PowerBuilder 11.5/DotNET/bin/System.Text.Json/System.Text.Json.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Sybase/PowerBuilder 11.5/System.Text.Json.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Sybase/PowerBuilder 11.5/System.Text.Json/System.Text.Json.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Sybase/PowerBuilder 11.5/DotNET/bin/System.Text.Json.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Sybase/PowerBuilder 11.5/DotNET/bin/System.Text.Json/System.Text.Json.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/user/Documents/project/bin/Release/System.Text.Json.DLL.
LOG: Assembly download was successful. Attempting setup of file: C:\Users\user\Documents\project\bin\Release\System.Text.Json.dll
LOG: Entering run-from-source setup phase.
LOG: Assembly Name is: System.Text.Json, Version=5.0.0.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51
WRN: Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: Revision Number
ERR: The assembly reference did not match the assembly definition found.
ERR: Run-from-source setup phase failed with hr = 0x80131040.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/user/Documents/project/bin/Release/System.Text.Json/System.Text.Json.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/user/Documents/project/bin/Release/System.Text.Json.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/user/Documents/project/bin/Release/System.Text.Json/System.Text.Json.EXE.
LOG: All probing URLs attempted and failed.
```

Comment: "I can't put a .config file on the production EXE" - why not? Assembly binding redirects are basically a fact of life in .NET... trying to work without them is going to be *really* painful.

Comment: Because it doesn't really depends on me, the production executables are a single executable file generated by the IDE, and the config would have to be put manually and could easily get lost by the users, also it's not that I want to work without them exactly, I just can't have another file outside of the executable.

Comment: You're basically stuck then, I'm afraid: without assembly binding redirects, you'll have to align *all* of your dependencies so that every single version exactly matches its expected dependencies. You may be able to do that for a few dependencies, but it's unlikely to scale to the large number of dependencies that most .NET applications use these days. You're really fighting against the ecosystem.